# c# Dependency Injection cannot convert lambda to intended delegate

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, lambda, dependency-injection

Cannot convert lambda to intended delegate because some of the return types in the block  are not implicitly converted to the delegate return type.

without DI

```
var chromeDriverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddArguments(new List<string>() { "headless" });

ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverService, chromeOptions);
```

with DI in Startup.cs

```
 services.AddScoped<ChromeDriverService>((serviceProvider =>
 {
   return  ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
 }));
 //**** errors here*****
 services.AddScoped<ChromeOptions>((serviceProvider =>
 { return new ChromeOptions().AddArguments(new List<string>() { "headless" }); }));
 // errors here******
 // how would i pass the driver service & options 
 services.AddScoped<ChromeDriver>(
 (serviceProvider =>
 {
   return new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverService,chromeOptions);
 }));
```

how do i make it so it's convertible and pass the correct options to the chromeDriver ?

Comment: What does `.AddArguments(...);` return?  Is it an instance of `ChromeOptions`?

Comment: Do you have any services that depends on `Chrome Options` and `ChromeDiverService` apart from `ChromeDriver`? if so, you may want to consider registering only `ChromeDriver`

Comment: yeah see it news up a chromeoptions as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an issue within this line:

```
services.AddScoped<ChromeOptions>((serviceProvider =>
{ return new ChromeOptions().AddArguments(new List<string>() { "headless" }); }));
```

`AddScoped` input delegate is excepted to return `ChromeOptions` while `.AddArguments` returns `void`

How about:

```
services.AddScoped<ChromeOptions>((serviceProvider =>
{
    var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
    chromeOptions.AddArguments(new List<string>() {"headless"});
    return chromeOptions; // Return expected type
});

services.AddScoped<ChromeDriver>((s => 
{
     return new ChromeDriver(s.GetService<ChromeDriverService>(), 
                             s.GetService<ChromeOptions>());
}));
```

Comment: That does work :) thx, but I how to pass them to services.AddScoped<ChromeDriver>  ?

Comment: I got it  services.AddScoped<ChromeDriver>(
             (s => 
             {
             return new ChromeDriver(s.GetService<ChromeDriverService>(), s.GetService<ChromeOptions>());
             })); , please update your answer, your also missing a ) at the end.